# Implementing global countdown scope of whole app in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, nstimer, countdown

I would like to implement a global scope countdown. NSTimer must continue to count down when user go to another view.

I check a regular way but I guess it will work only in current view scope.

So what is the method or way I should try.

Comment: You could always put it on the `AppDelegate`

Comment: I thought so but also worried about memory management. what do you think? The user may not use the view but it will implement on AppDelegate.

Comment: You should consider implementing your own singleton class just for this purpose. Abusing the application delegate is not a good design pattern. It's there for handling application level events only.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about memory; a single timer isn't going to do much.  (If you had dozens or hundreds, it would be a different story.)  I agree with @Desdenova about the App Delegate in theory, but this sounds like an application-level event to me.

Comment: Dear Desdenova and Sapi, I did what I want to do by implementing my own singleton class. Thanks for your helps.